# Qt Creator does not build (Qt 5.3, latest Qt creator code)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to build Qt creator. Qt lib built just fine on same machine.

I obtainerd qt creator using seemingly standard

```
 git clone --recursive https://git.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator.git
```

And with Qt 5.3, I have:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DCORE_LIBRARY -DIDE_LIBRARY_BASENAME=\"lib\" -DQT_CREATOR -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_USE_FAST_OPERATOR_PLUS -DQT_USE_FAST_CONCATENATION -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040900 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_HELP_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_CONCURRENT_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_SCRIPT_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/opt/Qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/opt/qt-creator/src/plugins/coreplugin -I../../../src -I/opt/qt-creator/src/libs -I/opt/qt-creator/tools -I/opt/qt-creator/src/plugins -I/opt/qt-creator/src/shared/scriptwrapper -I/opt/Qt5/include -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtPrintSupport -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtHelp -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtConcurrent -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtSql -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtScript -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtNetwork -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5/include/QtCore -I.moc/release-shared -I.uic -I. -o .obj/release-shared/tabpositionindicator.o /opt/qt-creator/src/plugins/coreplugin/tabpositionindicator.cpp
/opt/qt-creator/src/plugins/coreplugin/iwizardfactory.cpp: In member function ‘bool Core::IWizardFactory::isAvailable(const QString&) const’:
/opt/qt-creator/src/plugins/coreplugin/iwizardfactory.cpp:198: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
/opt/qt-creator/src/plugins/coreplugin/iwizardfactory.cpp:198: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
/opt/qt-creator/src/plugins/coreplugin/iwizardfactory.cpp:198: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
/opt/qt-creator/src/plugins/coreplugin/iwizardfactory.cpp:198: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
make[3]: *** [.obj/release-shared/iwizardfactory.o] Error 1
```

Any clue how to avoid error is appreciated. System is CentOS 6 (CERN clone)

Comment: Please post Which gcc version, git branch, commit sha. Also try to pull changes maybe this issue already fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no guarantees that the HEAD will build. Check out a release branch/tag instead.

Comment: Yes, built some previous version of Qt Creator via examining which commit corresponds to it. Why can't they offer a command to do that pull (from last stable version) on their very page about building it? Good that I am familiar with git and things.

Comment: @AskarIbragimov If you're using git, you're supposed to know what you're doing. The releases are tagged, so you don't need to do anything fancy here to determine "which commit corresponds to it". Just switch to the relevant tag. Instead of using git, you can always build from the distributed released sources. The initial download is much smaller. With git, of course, updates to newer versions are comparatively tiny.